# Writing Global Function in Go -- like append()

Tags: go

The Question is simple - how can i implement a package independent global function in golang.

ID, if i have a function in an package called core then from another package i need core.Function() to call that function. But i In go implementation there are some functions like - make(), append() for slice that can used without any import and within any package directly. If i wanted to write function like this what is the way of doing this? how can i write any function like this if it is possible.

Comment: By theory, its not possible/not authorize to do that. In golang any function you want that should be under a package.


`Package builtin provides documentation for Go's predeclared identifiers. The items documented here are not actually in package builtin but their descriptions here allow godoc to present documentation for the language's special identifiers.`
https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/
If you take a look at the content of http://golang.org/src/pkg/builtin/builtin.go You will notice that there are only declarations

Comment: Why would you need this? Organizing code into packages and calling them through their package name is a nice way to clarify where the function is coming from and what it does.

Comment: `append`, `make`, `new` and almost all "functions" in package [`builtin`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/) are actually better thought of as macros. They are not real functions, they get re-written by the compiler and end up calling different code, depending on types, special cases and other stuff. This becomes obvious when you think about the fact that you can pass a type as an argument.

Comment: IMO the @thwd's comment should be treated as *the* answer. While those answered actually explained how one could use "dot import" to make a function appear to be global, real built-in function *behave* differently, and that's a crucial point not to be missed.

Answer (score 12):

It's not possible to do exactly what you want but you can get somewhat close to it by using a dot-import. E.g. if you dot-import the `fmt` package, you can spell `fmt.Println` as just `Println`:

```
package main

import . "fmt"

func main() {
    Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/--dWV6PHYA.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: you can't. Go has builtin functions and types, but even the language designers try to keep their number to a minimum and avoid them if possible. For instance, there is a builtin `printf` function, but it is recommended to use `fmt.Printf` instead, as the builtin function "is not guaranteed to stay in the language".

While having to prepend the package name every time you use a function may appear cumbersome, it has its obvious advantages (makes code easier to read, avoids name collisions) and isn't actually as bad as it sounds if the package designer followed the guidelines described under "Naming package contents" in [this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/package-names).

Example: to create a `Regexp` object from a pattern string, you call `regexp.Compile()`, not `regexp.CompileRegexp()` - since you use the package name when calling a function, the name of the function can be shortened. This is of course lost if you use the "dot import" as per Ainar-G's suggestion. Then you would have just `Compile()`, which might be confusing ("compile what?").